# DDL of a temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I do not have the ability to create tables currently; however, I can create temp tables.

I am trying to materialize a view and then look at the DDL of the materialized view.

If I take the results of a view and insert all of the records into a #temp table, is there a way I can view that table's DDL?

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
select col_1, col_2, ..., col_10
into #temp_table
```

How can I view the DDL for the temp table?

**Edit #1:**

This is what I tried doing:

```
select
    'test' as [test]
into
    #myTemptable;
go

select *
from
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[Columns]
where
    table_name like '#myTempTable%';
go
```

Comment: I am playing with it, but I don't believe so.

Comment: Edited my post to reflect what I did.

Comment: That didn't give me much either. I invite you to try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Also, what I put in my edited question, is what another poster on that thread said to do.

Comment: Let me try again.

Comment: I was expecting some sort of create statement, but upon closer inspection, I can get what I need.

This solves my problem.

Comment: Post as the answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I could, but I hate having my posts closed lol

Comment: True ;( *insert 8 more characters so I can add comment*

Comment: That last comment deserves 10x upvotes.

Comment: Here you go, there there feel better. This too shall pass... Seriously, the reason why duplicates are closed, and why some people get impatient, is because so many questions can be answered with `insert_favourite_search_engine`. And as a developer, sysadmin and DBA, let me tell you that 99% of issues I encounter on a day-to-day basis can be answered like that.

Comment: but I want to look cool for having lots of SO points :(

Comment: @LunchBox then answer the tricky questions - thats how I keep my skills sharp.